# Privacy with new windows accounts?

Tags: windows, security, login, privacy, hotmail

Windows 8 is insisting me to use Hotmail account to login into operating system. Having this, will it be possible to identify me with Internet Explorer from any site?

**UPDATE**

If I go to Hotmail site with IE it takes me in automatically. So, any site, having Hotmail OpenID will know who I am, right?

Comment: That is the point of a Microsoft Account.  Hotmail OpenID has actually been discontinued for the most part.  Only Microsoft services uses.  Its no different then having a Google account

Comment: I can sign out of Google account and continue to use my computer.

Comment: You can do that even if you link your local account to a Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 0):

I came to conclusion, that the probable answer is "NO". Of course, there can be some undocumented means to transmit ID from Internet Explorer, but we talk about definite things. In known world the only mean to transmit ID from browser to site are cookies.

The cookies for Live ID are stored in the registry, under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\AuthCookies. They can be deleted from there and automatic login into Hotmail and other Live ID services stop. Also it can be set permissions to that registry branch, so that nothing could put cookies there back again.

Found here:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dee2079b-a614-4645-b377-dc87ac67f51d/disable-automatic-microsoft-website-signon-in-ie10?forum=ieitprocurrentver